# Does drinking matcha tea reduce LDL cholesterol in humans?

Tags: nutrition, tea, cholesterol

Matcha is a "[stone-ground Japanese-style green tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matcha)". There have been many health claims associated with it. In particular, it is said to be good for cholesterol levels:

For example:

- [Noble House](http://www.noble-house.tk/en/products/food/gula-java-performance-drinks/gula-java-matcha/superfood-matcha-is-good-for-cholesterol-and-heart)

  > Matcha has a cholesterol reducing effect. Matcha reduces the total cholesterol level and (bad) LDL-cholesterol and increases the good HDL cholesterol.
- [BodyBuilding.com](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/8-wonders-of-matcha-green-tea.html)

  > LOWERS LDL "BAD" CHOLESTEROL
  > A 2011 study featured in the American Journal of Clinical Nutrition demonstrated that administration of green tea beverages or extracts significantly lowered serum total cholesterol and LDL "Evil Emperor Zurg" cholesterol concentrations.
- [Match Source](http://matchasource.com/health-benefits-of-matcha-tea/)

  > Lowers cholesterol and blood sugar
- [Health and Natural World](http://www.healthyandnaturalworld.com/health-benefits-of-matcha-tea/)

  > Matcha tea lowers LDL (bad) cholesterol and at the same time increases the levels of HDL (good) cholesterol, which helps with the prevention of cardiovascular disease.

Does drinking matcha tea reduce LDL cholesterol in humans?

Comment: Please add citations to places where people are claiming its health benefits.  Un-referenced questions are likely to be deleted from this site.

Comment: @DenisStallings I believe we only require sources AFTER a google search turns up negative, but in this case, asking for a notability source is inappropriate, because there's a ton examples out there: https://www.google.com/search?q=matcha+tea+health

Comment: @SysDragon : The question whether Matcha Tea is benefitial is to vague to be on-topic on this website. If you don't want to have your question closed, please provide a specific claim.

Comment: @SysDragon No, we require sources regardless.  I followed your link and the first 7 links had 5 click-bait articles each claiming different stuff.  It is unfair to the other users and readers of this site to expect them to have to dig through a google search.  Which claim are you asking about?  What benefits are you asking about?  You can't expect a responder to go through every claim on every link on your google search.

Comment: I've focussed the question onto one claim. If you have further questions about matcha, please ask separate questions. (I'd suggest holding back until you get some answers on this one, in case they address your other concerns.)

Comment: Is the question whether matcha is better than other green tea, other tea, other drinks, other food?  So a study about green tea in general would, or would not, answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21715508) that confirms green tea (including matcha) causes significant reduction in LDL-cholesterol (aka bad cholesterol) concentration. I read that in this [article](https://blog.piquetea.com/matcha-green-tea/) which contains first-hand matcha information from renowned tea farmers and teamasters.

The PubMed abstract:

> **Green tea intake lowers fasting serum total and LDL cholesterol in
> adults: a meta-analysis of 14 randomized controlled trials.**
>
> Zheng XX1,
> Xu YL, Li SH, Liu XX, Hui R, Huang XH. Author information
>
> Abstract
>
> BACKGROUND:
>
> The effect of green tea beverage and green tea extract on lipid
> changes is controversial.
>
> OBJECTIVE:
>
> We aimed to identify and quantify the effect of green tea and its
> extract on total cholesterol (TC), LDL cholesterol, and HDL
> cholesterol.
>
> DESIGN:
>
> We performed a comprehensive literature search to identify relevant
> trials of green tea beverages and extracts on lipid profiles in
> adults. Weighted mean differences were calculated for net changes in
> lipid concentrations by using fixed-effects or random-effects models.
> Study quality was assessed by using the Jadad score, and a
> meta-analysis was conducted.
>
> RESULTS:
>
> Fourteen eligible randomized controlled trials with 1136 subjects were
> enrolled in our current meta-analysis. Green tea consumption
> significantly lowered the TC concentration by 7.20 mg/dL (95% CI:
> -8.19, -6.21 mg/dL; P < 0.001) and significantly lowered the LDL-cholesterol concentration by 2.19 mg/dL (95% CI: -3.16, -1.21
> mg/dL; P < 0.001). The mean change in blood HDL-cholesterol
> concentration was not significant. Subgroup and sensitivity analyses
> showed that these changes were not influenced by the type of
> intervention, treatment dose of green tea catechins, study duration,
> individual health status, or quality of the study. Overall, no
> significant heterogeneity was detected for TC, LDL cholesterol, and
> HDL cholesterol; and results were reported on the basis of
> fixed-effects models.
>
> CONCLUSION:
>
> The analysis of eligible studies showed that the administration of
> green tea beverages or extracts resulted in significant reductions in
> serum TC and LDL-cholesterol concentrations, but no effect on HDL
> cholesterol was observed.